# AngularJS: Base64 image with url

Tags: angularjs, image, base64

I want to add an image via **base64** like this:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

But I have an URL with the base64 part (`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA...`).

I don't know how to do it... Because this is not working:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{myUrl}}" />
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the myUrl should be there in the scope 
`<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{myUrl}}" />`